# How can I obtain the community login URL for community build with site.com or community builder?

Tags: community, authentication

I have been using some kind of shorthand to bookmark and login to salesforce ,something like below format for normal login

https://login.salesforce.com/login.jsp?un=&pw=

where un and pw are username and passwords that i keep as bookmark .

For Portal also I have something as below format

https://login.salesforce.com/secur/login_portal.jsp?orgId=&portalId=&un=&pw=

where Org Id is organization Id and PortalId is my portal Id

I need same for communities that have login enabled with site.com or community builder for bookmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the alternate route for this .I registered a force.com domain first for creating sites .

Once I did that ,I followed below format to login ,

```
https://{!hostname}.force.com/communityname/login?un=&pw=
```

where hostname is the one i see on URL from Community set up and communityname is the Name of my community and un and pw will need to be populated with username and passwords respectively .